# How to Mock jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().execute(); method?

Tags: spring, mockito, jdbctemplate

My question is how to mock

```
jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().execute("TRUNCATE table TABLE_1");
```

method?

It's return value is void if I am right.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {

    @Mock
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    ...
```

//I tried this but of course it doesn't work
 `doReturn(void).when(jdbcTemplate).getJdbcTemplate().execute("TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_1");`

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What's the mock here? `jdbcTemplate` or the return value of `getJdbcTemplate`?

Comment: Hi Fred, The mock is here the jdbcTemplate.

Comment: So what's the desired goal? To my understanding if `getJdbcTemplate` is not final then its return value will be `null` if not properly mocked. Do you want to mock it to return another mock object and verify that `execute` is called on it?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to verify whether execute is called  or not.

Comment: Ok, so my problem here is that every documentation I find referencing `getJdbcTemplate` say this method is final and to the best of my knowledge to do this with mockito you would need to use `mock-maker-inline`. Is it correct that in your case your `getJdbcTemplate` is final?

Comment: No it is not final.   public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        Assert.state(this.classicJdbcTemplate instanceof JdbcTemplate, "No JdbcTemplate available");
        return (JdbcTemplate)this.classicJdbcTemplate;
    }

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, my understanding is that `getJdbcTemplate` is not final and you're interested in mocking its return value so you can verify method calls.

Here's the approach I'd take:

```
// create a mock for the return value
@Mock
JdbcTemplate template;

// create a mock for the factory
@Mock
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Before
public void setUp() {
  // other initializations here

  // configure the factory to return the above mocked template
  when(jdbcTemplate. getJdbcTemplate()).thenReturn(template);
}
```

Now you should be able to verify on the `template` mock:

```
verify(template).execute("TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_1");
```